# Core Data and separate undo managers for multiple windows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

My Core Data app (not document-based) has two windows. Each window contains a table view with (different) data from the same NSManagedObjectContext. I use this code in both window controllers to enable undo support:

```
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window {
    return [[(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] undoManager];
}
```

The downside of this is that the user will undo changes he made in one window, while he is working in the other window. And even if the user chooses to close one of the windows, the undo manager will still undo changes in the closed window. The obvious solution to this problem is to use two separate NSUndoManager objects, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried using NSManagedObjectContexts "-setUndoManager:" with an individual undo manager for each window, but I could not find a suitable place to put the code, so I tried this:

```
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window {
    [[(CAppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] setUndoManager:self.myUndoManager];
    return self.myUndoManager;
}
```

It didn't work very well. (Undo steps disappeared when switching between windows.)

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what multiple contexts are for. See [Core Data Programming Guide - Change Management section](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ChangeManagement.html).